# htaccess redirect not redirecting all pages

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to implement an htaccess redirect and it is partially working. It will redirect the root domain http://oldsite.com/ to http://newsite.com/. However, when I try and do more such as http://oldsite.com/eng it will not redirect. Here is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is from a wordpress site that had two domains that pointed to the same folder on the server (same wordpress instance). We now want to phase out the old domain so whatever link you go to on http://oldsite.com/ will redirect to the correct part of http://newsite.com/.

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` in a new browser

Answer (score 0):

You should try and check for the old host before doing the redirect. If it's on the same server it will cause problems without it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```